# replicate drives after windows 7 is loaded

Tags: windows-7

Has anyone found a way to load windows 7 on a drive and when that is completed copy the drive to another drive.  I have the drive copier but I am being told you can not copy a drive because of the NewSid or should I say the lack of.  I have a drive duplicator that will go to waist if I can not copy drives after I make a good image.

Answer (score 1):

If you Sysprep the image after you complete the install then you should be able to make duplicates.

[Here](http://blog.brianleejackson.com/sysprep-a-windows-7-machine-%E2%80%93-start-to-finish-v2) is a step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

Well one option would be to create a hardware raid 1 mirror and then proceed to installation.
this is the hardware solution.  In terms of Software some ghost-like imaging products come to mind.

the sid should be fine as long as only 1 of the drives are online in a system at a time.  if you plan on having both up and running you would need to sysprep the system.